# Multithreading : Segmentation fault in Producer Consumer problem using semaphores and mutex

Tags: c, multithreading, mutex, semaphore

I'm trying to solve the producer consumer problem in c using threads, semaphores and mutex.

**Here is my code :**

Initialization :

```
sem_t empty; 
sem_t full; 
int ip = 0; 
int ic = 0; 
int *buffer;
pthread_mutex_t mutex;
```

Producer :

```
void* producer( void* pid) {
int x; 
while(1){
    srand(time(NULL));
    x = (rand()%9) + 1; 
    sem_wait(&empty);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    buffer[ip] = x; 
    printf("producer %d : Inserts item %d at %d \n", *((int *) pid), buffer[ip], ip);
    ip = (ip + 1) % sizeof(buffer)/sizeof(int);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    sem_post(&full);
}
return NULL;             
}
```

Consumer :

```
void* consumer(void *cid) {
int x; 
while(1){
    sem_wait(&full);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    x = buffer[ic];
    printf("consumer %d : gets item %d from %d \n", *(int *) cid, x, ic);
    ic = (ic + 1) % sizeof(buffer)/sizeof(int);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    sem_post(&empty);
}
    
return NULL;   
}
```

Main :

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    int nbProducers = atoi(argv[1]);
    int nbConsumers = atoi(argv[2]);
    int bufferSize = atoi(argv[3]);

    pthread_t producers[nbProducers];
    pthread_t consumers[nbConsumers];

    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);
    sem_init(&empty, 0, bufferSize);
    sem_init(&full, 0, 0);

    buffer = malloc(bufferSize * sizeof(int));

    for(int i = 0 ; i < nbProducers ; i++)
    {
        pthread_create(&producers[i], NULL, (void *)producer, NULL);
    }

    for(int i = 0 ; i < nbConsumers ; i++)
    {
        pthread_create(&consumers[i], NULL, (void *)consumer, NULL);
    }

    for(int i = 0 ; i < nbproducers ; i++)
    {
        pthread_join(producers[i], NULL);
    }

    for(int i = 0 ; i < nbconsumers ; i++)
    {
        pthread_join(consumers[i], NULL);
    }

    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);
    sem_destroy(&empty);
    sem_destroy(&full);

    free(buffer);

    return 0;
}
```

I am supposed to precise how much producers and consumers I want, as well as the buffer size.

My problem is that I have a segmentation fault, and I found that it occurs when initializing the first semaphore at this line in the main : **`sem_init(&empty, 0, bufferSize);`**

I don't understand why, is it because I haven't tested argc ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: did you use the compiler / linker options to include pthread support?

Comment: `ip = (ip + 1) % sizeof(buffer)/sizeof(int);` looks really odd for `int *buffer;`. `sizeof` a pointer gives you the size of the pointer, not the memory where it points to. It should be `ip = (ip + 1) % bufferSize;`

Comment: yes, this is how i compile : 
gcc -pthread test.c -o test
./test 2 3 4

Comment: @mch should it be sizeof(*buffer) then ?

Comment: Why do you cast your functions in the `pthread_create` calls to `(void*)`?

Comment: No, it should be `bufferSize`, the variable that you have in `main`, just make it global like the pointer.

Comment: because my consumer/producer function return types are void*

Comment: I tried to call it as a global variable, still doesn't work